# Connection to Oracle DB with Play Framework failed

Tags: oracle, jdbc, playframework, models, ebean

I have this exception when I am trying to connect my oracle database to my application on Play! Framework 2.1.5 (the problem concerns the ebean.default="models.*" line) :

```
Configuration error

path parameter: Invalid path ' - could not find datasource for default': Token not allowed in path expression: '-' (Invalid number: '-') (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)
In C:\MyApps\oracleCrud2\conf\application.conf at line 54.
51# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
52# By convention, the default server is named `default`
53#
54 ebean.default="models.*"
55
56# Logger
57# ~~~~~
58# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/), by providing a logger.xml file in the conf directory .
```

Some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you check your db.default lines to make sure they are correct.

Comment: Hey @wwkudu, my problem is resolved. Thanks for your consideration.
However, can you tell me how can I mark this question as resolved ?

Comment: Just type in the solution as an answer ("Post Your Answer" button at the bottom). That way anyone who comes along later with a similar issue will see how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. Here is the working part of the application.conf that deals with Oracle connection with Play! :

```
  db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/xe"
  db.default.user=play
  db.default.password=play
```

Hope that I helped, have a good one !

-Ramzi